# How can I copy from one string to another string from the desired location to the end?

Tags: c#, string

Suppose I have:

```
string abc="Your name = Hello World";
```

using length function I match the existence of an location of the `=`  operator, but how can I copy all the words that come after the `=`, such as "Hello Word", from this string to another one?

Answer (score 4):

```
string abc="Your name = Hello World";
abc.Substring(abc.IndexOf("=")+1); //returns " Hello World"
```

Answer (score 3):

There's several ways to do it. Here are a few examples...

Using `Split`:

```
string[] parts = abc.Split(new char[]{'='}, 2);
if (parts.Length != 2) { /* Error */ }
string result = parts[1].TrimStart();
```

Using `IndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
int i = abc.IndexOf('=');
if (i == -1) { /* Error */ }
string s = abc.Substring(abc, i).TrimStart();
```

Using a regular expression (probably overkill for this):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(abc, @"=\s*(.*)");
if (!match.Success) { /* Error */ }
string result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string newstring = abc.Substring(abc.IndexOf("=") + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string abc="Your name = Hello World";
    string[] newString = abc.Split('='); 
   /* 
      newString[0] is 'Your name '
      newString[1] is  ' Hello World'
   */
```